# CyberPanel LiteSpeed htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, litespeed

I'm using `CyberPanel`that it work with `litespeed`, I want to use `.htaccess` but it seems not reading any command in htaccess. for example I set:

`Deny from all`

But it not affacted. here is vHost conf:

```
rewrite  {
  enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because OLS only supports

**RewriteBase**

**RewriteCond**

**RewriteRule**

any other directive will be ignored and dropped.

if you want to do access control  , you can use RewriteRule to do so

e.g.

```
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

deny access to all

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

allow access for certain IP

You can further customize it to make a deny/allow equivalent

more detail [here](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/access-control/)

Comment: Although the OP references "LiteSpeed", not "OpenLiteSpeed"? LiteSpeed does support the access control directive `Deny from all`.

Comment: Yes, LiteSpeed Enterprise does fully support directive like Deny ,  but he posted a conf                                                                                    
`rewrite  {
  enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}`
  , this is only to OLS.